# How to override river-admin template?

Tags: django, workflow, django-river

Firstly , i would like to say that this package is amazing in the sense where there can be so much flexibility. Im relatively new to this package and im just trying to figure a way to fiddle around with the provided front end in the river-admin package. Could someone point me in the correct direction in doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of both `django-river` and `river-admin`.

`river-admin` is an admin interface for `django-river` implemented as a `Vue.js` application backed by `django-rest-framework`.

One fact about it is that it was never meant to use the `river-admin` as an extension to your django app which means that it doesn't have to fit in how your own django app looks. You might think of it is like the UI of Apache Airflow or RabbitMQ admin interface and so on.

But if you think that the things you wanna add are something that can be used by all of its other users why not contribute to [the repo](https://github.com/javrasya/river-admin). Otherwise, you can always fork the repo and do the custom changes that you can not do via the `river-admin` API, build the package by yourself.

[Here](https://github.com/javrasya/river-admin/blob/master/docs/contribute.rst) is some information on how one can build and run stuff locally